# Extract ID numeric value from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data set, I need to extract 9 numeric ID from the "Notes" column.
below some of the code I tried, but sometimes I don't get the correct output. sometimes there are few spaces between numbers, or a symbol, or sometimes there are numeric values that are not part of the ID etc.. any idea how to do this more efficient?

```
DF['Output'] = DF['Notes'].str.replace(' '+' '+' '+'-', '')
DF['Output'] = DF['Notes'].str.replace(' '+' '+'-', '')
DF['Output'] = DF['Notes'].str.replace(' '+'-', '')
DF['Output'] = DF['Notes'].str.replace('-', '')

DF['Output'] = DF['Notes'].str.replace('\D', ' ')

DF['Output'] = DF['Notes'].str.findall(r'(\d{9,})').apply(', '.join)
```

| Notes | Expected Output |
| --- | --- |
| ab. 325% xyz | 0 |
| GHY12345678 9 | 123456789 |
| FTY 234567 891 | 234567891 |
| BNM 567 891 524; 123 Ltd | 567891524 |
| 2.5%mnkl, 3234 56 78 9; TGH 1235 z | 323456789 |
| RTF 956 327-12 8 TYP | 956327128 |
| X Y Z 1.59% 2345 567 81; one 35 in | 234556781 |
| VTO 126%, 12345 67 | 0 |
| 2.6% 1234 ABC 3456 1 2 4 91 | 345612491 |

Answer (score 1):

```
# replace known character in b/w the numbers with null
# extract the 9 digits
df['output']=(df['Notes'].str.replace(r'[\s|\-]','',regex=True)
              .str.extract(r'(\d{9})').fillna(0))
df
```

```
    Notes                           Expected Output     output
0   ab. 325% xyz                                 0          0
1   GHY12345678 9                        123456789  123456789
2   FTY 234567 891                       234567891  234567891
3   BNM 567 891 524; 123 Ltd             567891524  567891524
4   2.5%mnkl, 3234 56 78 9; TGH 1235 z   323456789  323456789
5   RTF 956 327-12 8 TYP                 956327128  956327128
6   X Y Z 1.59% 2345 567 81; one 35 in   234556781  234556781
7   VTO 126%, 12345 67                           0  0
8   2.6% 1234 ABC 3456 1 2 4 91          345612491  345612491
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.replace` to first strip off spaces and dashes, followed by `str.extract` to find 9 digit numbers, we can try:

```py
DF["Output"] = DF["Notes"].str.replace('[ -]+', '', regex=True)
                          .str.extract(r'(?<!\d)(\d{9})(?!\d)')
```

For an explanation of the regex pattern, we place non digit boundary markers around `\d{9}` to ensure that we *only* match 9 digit numbers.  Here is how the regex works:

- `(?<!\d)` ensure that what precedes is a non digit OR the start of the column
- `(\d{9})` match and capture exactly 9 digits
- `(?!\d)` ensure that what follows is a non digit OR the end of the column

Comment: Smart use of replace then extract, nice one